# call only required field/attribute from the different models into a view model in asp.net mvc 5 without using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two different models. `UserPersonalDetail` and `UserEducationalDetails`

I want to populate some of the fields from the above two models into view model called `UserViewModel`.

I tried but I'm getting all the fields from both models.

```
public class UserEducationalDetails
{
    public Boolean Undergraduate { get; set; }

    public Boolean PostGraduate { get; set; }

    public String CollegeName { get; set; }

    public String SchoolName { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class UserPersonalDetail
{
    public String  FullName {get; set;}

    public string  FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FatherName { get; set; }

    public string placeofBirth { get; set; }

    public string MarriedStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I expect User view model should come as

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    //Want to view the only following fields from UserPersonalDetails and UserEducationalDetails Model
    //From UserEducationalDetails Model

    public UserEducationalDetails CollegeName { get; set; }

    public UserEducationalDetails SchoolName { get; set; }

    //From UserEducationalDetails Model

    public UserPersonalDetail FullName {get; set;}

    public UserPersonalDetail MarriedStatus { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: All these, `CollegeName`, `SchoolName` etc. should be `string`s.

Comment: This collegeNAme and SchoolName is part of the UserEducationalDetails Model. I want those feild should be in UserviewModel.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how the model classes are working. For example, when you define this:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public UserEducationalDetails CollegeName { get; set; }
}
```

it doesn't mean that the CollegeName is taken from a `UserEducationalDetails` model, it means it *is* a UserEducationalDetails model. This is clearly not what you intend. What you want to do is to read off the properties when you construct the `UserViewModel`, something like this:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    // Types reflect the types used in the models
    public string CollegeName { get; private set; }

    public string SchoolName { get; private set; }

    public string FullName {get; private set;}

    public string MarriedStatus { get; private set; }

    public UserViewModel(UserEducationalDetails ued, UserPersonalDetails upd)
    {
        // Copy the properties that are relevant to this object
        CollegeName = ued.CollegeName;
        SchoolName = ued.SchoolName;
        FullName = upd.FullName;
        MarriedStatus = upd.MarriedStatus;
    }
}
```